# Hacer click en input image con vba webscraping

Tags: vba, imagen, input, scraping

estoy intentando hacer web scraping con vba. El problema es que no logro hacer 'click' en el boton consultar, da error, aparentemente puedo acceder al input que contiene la imagen 'consultar'. Lo que trato de hacer son procesos recursivos que seleccionen cada elemento del select y luego clic en consultar para terminar extrayendo las tasas aduaneras para cada posicion de cada capitulo del ncm, pero para simplificar el codigo me alcanzaria por ahora poder hacer clic para al menos un elemento de la primer pagina.
Muchas gracias

El codigo vba:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Scraping
End Sub


Sub Scraping()
    Dim IE As Object
    dim URL = "https://www.afip.gob.ar/aduana/arancelintegrado/default.asp"
    dim txtN1, txtN2
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    
txtN1 = "SELECCIONE CAPITULO"
txtN2 = "SECCION"

 Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate URL
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim a As Object, currentOption As Object

        Set a = .document.getElementsByName("consultar")
            
        For Each currentOption In .document.getElementsByTagName("Option")
            If (InStr(currentOption.innerText, txtN1) + InStr(currentOption.innerText, txtN2)) = 0 Then
                currentOption.Selected = True
                
                a.Click
                Exit For
                
             End If
        Next currentOption

        '.Quit
    End With
End Sub
```